# Access denied when outputting to filename using variable

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

Windows 10, in my own Videos folder under UserProfile.

I'm trying to string together a couple of things to make a complete txt file containing various information, in one single command line, right.

The goal is to make a single txt with a header, some generated information and a footer. The txt will be named the same thing as the folder name with `.txt` at the end, for simplicity's sake.

I'm aiming to run the string of commands once per folder, and since there are quite a few calls to the folder's name that's being targeted, I figured to use a variable to shorten it.

`type header.txt > VeryLongFolderNameFooBar\VeryLongFolderNameFooBar.txt & c:\mediainfo\mediainfo.exe --output=file://template.txt ./VeryLongFolderNameFooBar/*.mkv >> VeryLongFolderNameFooBar\VeryLongFolderNameFooBar.txt & type footer.txt >> VeryLongFolderNameFooBar\VeryLongFolderNameFooBar.txt`

This worked absolutely perfectly, but got quite tedious to change the folder name for all occurrences, so why not use a variable right?

`set a=VeryLongFolderNameFooBar && type header.txt>%a%\%a%.txt & c:\mediainfo\mediainfo.exe --output=file://template.txt ./%a%/*.mkv>>%a%\%a%.nfo & type footer.txt>>%a%\%a%.txt`

This gives three `access denied` messages. Initially I was using spaces before and after the variable calls and removed them after reading a post that spaces can mess things up, but still no avail and I am really stuck on this. When I do `echo %a%` it returns the folder name with no issues at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: For your actual goal (not your Q) instead of repeating the filename you could do `(type header & mediainfo blah & type footer) >outputfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD scans the entire line for variables
before it actually processes any of it. 
Therefore, it replaces `%a%` with null
(or whatever it was previously set to)
before it processes the `set a=...` command. 
You'll need to do that on a separate line:

```
set a=VeryLongFolderNameFooBar
type header.txt>%a%\%a%.txt & c:\mediainfo\mediainfo.exe --output=file://template.txt ./%a%/*.mkv>>%a%\%a%.nfo & type footer.txt>>%a%\%a%.txt
```

---

But, in addition (as you discovered), the `set` command
(stupidly, IMHO) includes everything up to a command separator. 
So

```
set a=SoLong & echo /%a%/
```

will set `a` to `SoLong`  (with a trailing space). 
One way to handle that is to leave out the space before the `&`:

```
set a=SoLong& echo ...
```

but that's widely considered to be less readable. 
A slightly nicer solution
is to put the `set` command in parentheses:

```
(set a=SoLong) & echo ...
```

so the value gets terminated by the `)`.

Comment: ```echo %a%
VeryLongFolderNameFooBar    

type header.txt>%a%\%a%.txt& c:\_yaiba\mediainfo\mediainfo.exe --output=file://template.txt ./%a%/*.mkv>>%a%\%a%.txt & type footer.txt>>%a%\%a%.txt  
Access denied.  
Access denied.  
Access denied.```

Edit: I was unable to do the linebreaks but I hope it's legible anyway.

Comment: Turns out it actually works fine if you *only* set the variable on its own sole line. 
  Since I echo'd %a% and it returned the correct result I figured it would work anyway.

  Also, after testing again, it seems that the space was the issue. My initial line worked, had I only removed the first space after the variable name.

  `set a=VeryLongFolderNameFooBar&type header.txt` etc worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the trailing space issue; I keep forgetting about that.

Comment: Or `set "var=value" & blahblah` -- but not `set var="value"` which includes the quotemarks _and_ trailing space. Also, if DELAYEDEXPANSION is enabled you can `set "a=value" & use !a! on same line` -- which is easy in a batchfile (script) but a bit of a nuisance interactively.